# Swift - unwanted margin in xib

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, xib

So I have some strange margins to the left and right of my app:

Here is one xib:

[image]

And here's another xib from the same app:

[image]

And here's the corresponding views from XCode (6.1.1):

[image]

and

[image]

Does anyone have any thoughts about how I might fix this? I suspect my UINavigationController is misconfigured?

I tried `view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero` to no avail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this in view did load

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

and in case of auto layout constraint

1) select the view and the main view and give them equal width.
2) make the table view horizontally center in superview.
3) top and bottom whatever you want.

i think this will solve your problem.

Comment: I used "equal widths" (between the UIScrollView and the UIView, and between the UIView and the UIScrollView) instead of "horizontal center in container" and it worked! Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 ways to set constraints without margin:

1) from the pin panel - uncheck the option 'constraint to margin':

[image]

2) After you set the constraint, select the constraint and go to the size inspector, uncheck the option 'Relative to margin' :

[image]

3) With ctrl drag - press alt (option) to toggle between the options without margin:

[image]